# How to save a file and move it to desired location before it is downloaded (python,selenium)? Using chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium chrome webdriver. I have access to a webpage where I enter my credentials and after that I have a button which I click to download the file as a csv (which goes directly to my downloads folder).

Ideally, I would like to send that downloaded csv file to another folder and rename it.

My code is as follows:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import date
d = datetime.datetime.now() 
dayprueba="%d/%d/%d"%(d.month, d.day, d.year)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#acceder a pagina web
driver.get ("MY URL")


emailbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-0"]') #encuentra pagina web
emailbox.send_keys('MY EMAIL') #escribe el usuario

passwordbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-1"]')
passwordbox.send_keys('MY PASS')


botondeingreso = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-manual-login/div/div/div/form/button')
botondeingreso.click()

sleep(2)

botonreportes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-dashboard/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/wui-dashboard-tile/div/div/div[3]/wui-button/button")
botonreportes.click()

#bajado de tablas de argentina
#bajado de tabla de orders

botonfechaargentina = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-2"]')
botonfechaargentina.send_keys('1/1/2018')

sleep(1)


flechaprov = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-select-3"]/div/div[2]')
flechaprov.click()
sleep(1)

botonprovinciasargentinas= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-option-12"]/span')
botonprovinciasargentinas.click()

sleep(1)

botondefechadehoy= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-3"]')
botondefechadehoy.send_keys(dayprueba)

clickearafueradelapantalla= driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-reports/div')
clickearafueradelapantalla.click()

botondedescargaAR = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-reports/div/form/div[4]/button')
botondedescargaAR.click()
```

There at the last step the click button works fine, but the download goes directly to C:\Users\barra\Downloads (which is my download folder and want to move it to another one).

Any help is appreciated!!

thank you

[The image show the name of downloaded file, I want to change it to orders_ar, everything from the first "_" I want to remove and change for "ar"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtGNc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the chromedriver downloads path using chrome preferences as shown below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "/your/desired/path"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
``
Make sure you add these line before `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`
```